# How to open save dialog box for saving pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I truly appreciate your suggestions. I am using MVC3 and I want user to save to his own path by opening a dialog with password protected. Can you guys please help me on this.

Below is my code:

```
mydoc.GenerateLetter(PdfData);               

string WorkingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
{
   m.Write(mydoc.DocumentBytes, 0, mydoc.DocumentBytes.Length);
   m.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   string OutputFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, PdfData.Name + ".pdf");

   using (Stream output = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
   {
      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(m);
      PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, "abc123", "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a Save As dialog so that the user can choose the location to save the PDF file on his computer you could use the Content-Disposition HTTP header and set it to attachment. Also in an ASP.NET MVC application instead of saving the file to the server (which is what your code currently does), you should stream it to the client:

```
public ActionResult DownloadPdf()
{
    var mydoc = ...
    mydoc.GenerateLetter(PdfData);
    byte[] pdf = mydoc.DocumentBytes;
    var reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
    using (var encrypted = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, encrypted, true, "abc123", "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
        return File(encrypted.ToArray(), "application/pdf", PdfData.Name + ".pdf");
    }
}
```

Now when a user navigates to this controller action `/SomeController/DownloadPdf` he will be presented with a Save As dialog allowing him to download the encrypted PDF file and store it in a chosen location on his computer.